# How can I mass organize more than 40 apps on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

So I had to format my phone recently and redownloaded all my apps. Unfortunately now I have to reorder more than 40 apps on my phone! iTunes used to have a feature that can allow us to edit and organize apps on the iPhone, which have been removed with the recent update.

Is there any other way I can easily reorder and organize my app list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no. However Apple still has the last version of iTunes with App Management still available for download, [here.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208079)

You can download and replace your current (newer version) with this one, though you *may* (not sure, though I would...) have to delete your newer version before installing this.